# How to solve JavaScript rounding problem?

Tags: javascript

Let's have an input type text field. Now type into 4444.40, get the input value in JS, multiply by 100, and try to obtain exactly 444440. No chance. Just try this:

```
let num = 4444.40
let multiplied = num * 100
console.log(multiplied)
```

You will get 444439.99999999994. How to solve this?

Comment: That's how floating point numbers work. What's the overall context/goal?

Comment: For anyone that wants to know why this happens: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 0):

This is how floating point math works in JavaScript. You'll need to round the product to get a whole number.

To get more precise, first multiply by a larger factor (say 10,000), then round that and then divide back down by the same amount.

```js
let num = 4444.40
let multiplied = num * 100
num = Math.round(multiplied);
console.log(num)
```

Comment: @Spectric I've said more that "Math.round()"?